# Return value from a stored proc on error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

I have an sp in SQL Server that when errors returns -4

What does -4 mean? Is there a table somewhere explaining what the possible return values are?

---

There must be some standard

For example

```
declare @RetVal int  
EXEC @RetVal = stpTest  
select @RetVal
```

where stpTest is "SELECT 1/0" returns -6.

-6 must mean something!

---

The sp that returned -4 only has UPDATE and SELECT INTO statements in it.

At no point does it do 'SELECT -4' so how can I "find out what -4 means in that particular stored procedure"?

Also, if there is no standard then why does a divide by zero error always return -6?

---

If you have an sp that does not return anything i.e. it doesn't have any select statements in it and you do:

```
declare @RetVal int  
EXEC @RetVal = yourSPName
```

Then @RetVal will have a value of 0.

If there is an error then @RetVal will be a value other then zero, for example if the only thing your sp does is "SELECT 1/0" then @RetVal will be -6.

Try it and see

My question is what do these return values mean? They must have some logical meaning!

Comment: As is stated repeatedly below, there are no standards.  If you have the source of the sproc, try your standard debugging procedures.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Please edit your question with a complete example, showing the stored procedure, the execution, and the result.

Answer (score 29):

If you have a RETURN statement with an explicit return value, that is of course the return value.

But if there is no RETURN statement, but an error occurs during execution, the return value is 10 minus the severity level of the error. Division by zero is level 16, thus the return value is -6. Permissions errors are typical level 14, thus the return value is -4.

As you may guess this is not terribly useful, but this: 0 is success, and everything else is an error.

Answer (score 10):

There is no standard for return codes. You'll have to find out what -4 means in that particular stored procedure. In fact, not all return codes are errors.

---

**EDIT: counter-example**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RetValTest] 
AS
BEGIN
    select 1/0;
END

GO
```

Execution:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[RetValTest]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Result:

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RetValTest, Line 9
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

This is with SQL Server 2008.

---

Some research suggests that this behavior may be left over from SQL Server 6.0. If that is the case, then you can decide for yourself how reliable it's likely to be, given that they stopped documenting it (and stopped guaranteeing its accuracy) so long ago.

---

My "research" is due, with thanks, to SQL Server MVP [Tibor Karaszi](http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/default.asp). His source is Books Online for SQL Server 6.5. Under ""Control-Of-Flow Language", RETURN", he found

> "SQL Server reserves 0 to indicate a successful return and 
> reserves negative values from - 1 through - 99 to indicate 
> different reasons for failure. If no user-defined return value is 
> provided, the SQL Server value is used. User-defined return status 
> values should not conflict with those reserved by SQL Server. The 
> values 0 through -14 are currently in use.

Comment: Ah ok, with SQL Server 2005 it's a bit different. RetValTest gives the same error message but "SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value" gives a -6

Comment: with sql2005 on the messages tab you get that error, in the results tab you get -6 - see my answer below

Comment: just ran your above example on SQL 2008 and got Return Value of -6 below the divide by zero error.

Try the following
Query > Results To > Results To Text

and run again, the Return Value is more obvious then...

Or you could try looking at the Results tab as suggested in my previous comment.

Having said all that, maybe different versions/different environments could cause us to see different answers, which still leaves the original question as valid. ie where does -6 come from?

Answer (score 5):

> For example
>
> ```
> declare @RetVal int  
> EXEC @RetVal = stpTest  
> select @RetVal
> ```
>
> where `stpTest` is `SELECT 1/0` returns -6.
>
> -6 must mean something!
>
> If you have an sp that does not return anything i.e. it doesn't have
>   any select statements in it and you do:
>
> ```
> declare @RetVal int  
> EXEC @RetVal = yourSPName
> ```
>
> Then `@RetVal` will have a value of 0.
>
> If there is an error then `@RetVal` will be a value other then zero,
>   for example if the only thing your sp does is `SELECT 1/0` then
>   `@RetVal` will be -6.
>
> Try it and see

---

First of all, thanks for bothering to craft an example that returns -6.

Here's [what the documentation says about -6](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/b39cb2e5-3d49-4266-84dc-565b11ad0ffa/):

> -6 Miscellaneous user error occurred.

-6 might be the most amorphous code that SQL Server returns.
Why? Because the -6 error code is essentially hiding an error deeper in the call stack.

After troubleshooting this error myself, here are my tips for troubleshooting this error:

1. If your DAL or application layer generates this error, then run the SQL code in SQL Server Management Studio **as the application user, *not* with your own SQL Server ID.** [Why? Because your permissions might not be the same.]
2. Make the SQL code under inspection as readable as possible. [Why? Because this error may lurk deep within the call stack.]
3. Failing all else, comment out half of the code. Is the error still occurring? Comment out 50% of the remaining code. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question should be edited to ask -

> What are the default return values if
>   you dont have a RETURN statement in
>   your stored proc?

Something I did find was from this link [www.redware.com/handbooks/sql_server_handbook/sql_server_stored_procedures.html](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_&_Return_Values)

> SQL Server will default the return
>   value to zero. The returned values are
>   typically used to return a status flag
>   from the stored procedure with a
>   non-zero value usually indicating
>   failure during processing.
>
> Returned values are difficult to
>   access using ODBC their use is
>   recommended only to return a success
>   or failure of the stored procedure
>   when communicating with other stored
>   procedures.

From this link - [sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_&_Return_Values](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_&_Return_Values)

> The return values -99 through 0 are
>   reserved for SQL Server internal use.
>   You can create your own parameters
>   that can be passed back to the calling
>   program.

Also another link (I guess) from @Erland Sommarskog [www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html)

> **Return Values from Stored Procedures**
>
> All stored procedures have a return
>   value, determined by the RETURN
>   statement. The RETURN statement takes
>   one optional argument, which should be
>   a numeric value. If you say RETURN
>   without providing a value, the return
>   value is 0 if there is no error during
>   execution. If an error occurs during
>   execution of the procedure, the return
>   value may be 0, or it may be a
>   negative number. The same is true if
>   there is no RETURN statement at all in
>   the procedure: the return value may be
>   a negative number or it may be 0.
>
> Whether these negative numbers have
>   any meaning, is a bit difficult to
>   tell. It used to be the case, that the
>   return values -1 to -99 were reserved
>   for system-generated return values,
>   and Books Online for earlier versions
>   of SQL Server specified meanings for
>   values -1 to -14. However, Books
>   Online for SQL 2000 is silent on any
>   such reservations, and does not
>   explain what -1 to -14 would mean.
>
> With some occasional exception, the
>   system stored procedures that
>   Microsoft ships with SQL Server return
>   0 to indicate success and any non-zero
>   value indicates failure.

**Getting Error Information**

Also if you need to find what the error is (rather than what -6 means) you could try putting your sql into a try catch, ie.

```
begin try

    select 1/0 as 'an error'

end try

begin catch

    select ERROR_NUMBER() as 'ERROR_NUMBER', 
           ERROR_SEVERITY() as 'ERROR_SEVERITY',
           ERROR_STATE() as 'ERROR_STATE',
           LEFT(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),50) as 'ERROR_PROCEDURE',
           ERROR_LINE() as 'ERROR_LINE' , 
           LEFT(ERROR_MESSAGE(),40) as 'ERROR_MESSAGE'    
end catch
```

Comment: @Steve: no, it's not the answer. Where does this explain -6? This is as likely to be garbage left over in a register as anything else.

Comment: This answer is not useful at all. It does not answer what has been asked and more like just giving a context around it

Answer (score 0):

I found this,I hope this helps.

```
Value Description
0 Procedure was executed successfully.
-1 Object is missing.
-2 Datatype error occurred.
-3 Process was chosen as deadlock victim.
-4 Permission error occurred.
-5 Syntax error occurred.
-6 Miscellaneous user error occurred.
-7 Resource error, such as out of space, occurred.
-8 Nonfatal internal problem was encountered.
-9 System limit was reached.
-10 Fatal internal inconsistency occurred.
-11 Fatal internal inconsistency occurred.
-12 Table or index is corrupt.
-13 Database is corrupt.
-14 Hardware error occurred.
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b39cb2e5-3d49-4266-84dc-565b11ad0ffa/negative-return-value-causes-error?forum=transactsql

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure there's a way to know this without asking the SQL Server devs. It's something lower level than your stored proc evaluating what you're sending it and generating that return code. Unless you've specifically got a *RETURN -4* in your code, it's coming from the SQL parser probably.