# SQL Server stored procedure return code oddity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

The client that calls this code is restricted and can only deal with return codes from stored procs. So, we modified our usual contract to `RETURN -1` on error and *default* to `RETURN 0` if no error

If the code hits the inner catch block, then the RETURN code default is -4 rather then 0

Does anyone know where this comes from please? With reference

Cheers
gbn

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.foo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.foo
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo (
    KeyCol  char(12) NOT NULL,
    ValueCol xml NOT NULL,
    Comment varchar(1000) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_foo PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (KeyCol)
)
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.bar') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE dbo.bar
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.bar
    @Key char(12),
    @Value xml,
    @Comment varchar(1000)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @StartTranCount tinyint;
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @StartTranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;

    IF @StartTranCount = 0 BEGIN TRAN;

    BEGIN TRY
        --SELECT @StartTranCount = 'fish' --generates an error and goes to outer CATCH
        INSERT dbo.foo (KeyCol, ValueCol, Comment) VALUES (@Key, @Value, @Comment);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 2627    --PK violation
            UPDATE
                dbo.foo
            SET
                ValueCol = @Value, Comment = @Comment
            WHERE
                KeyCol = @Key;
        ELSE
            RAISERROR ('Tits up', 16, 1);
    END CATCH

    IF @StartTranCount = 0 COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @StartTranCount = 0 AND XACT_STATE() <> 0 ROLLBACK TRAN;
    RETURN -1
END CATCH
--Without this, we'll send -4 if we hit the UPDATE CATCH block above
--RETURN 0
GO

--please run these **separately**

--Run with RETURN 0 and fish line commented out
DECLARE @rtn int
EXEC @rtn = dbo.bar 'abcdefghijkl', '<foobar />', 'testing'
SELECT @rtn; SELECT * FROM dbo.foo
GO

DECLARE @rtn int
EXEC @rtn = dbo.bar 'abcdefghijkl', '<foobar2 />', 'testing2'
--updated OK but we get @rtn = -4
SELECT @rtn; SELECT * FROM dbo.foo
GO

--uncomment fish line
DECLARE @rtn int
EXEC @rtn = dbo.bar 'abcdefghijkl', '<foobar />', 'testing'
--Hit outer CATCH, @rtn = -1 as expected
SELECT @rtn; SELECT * FROM dbo.foo
```

Comment: why are you assigning 'fish' to a tinyint?

Comment: To force an exception to test the outer CATCH block. See the last EXEC...

Comment: sorry already removed my comment before I saw your reply. (My comment was bogus anyway :)

Comment: Ken Henderson's guru guide lists [the same table as here](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pbarc/conn5/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/27897;pt=28076) but obviously no longer correct as -4 would be a permission error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In playing around with the procedure, I can get a a return -6, if I insert a null into foo.KeyCol and remove the RAISERROR in the inner catch.  This is something SQL Server is doing, and is documented here: [Return Values from Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#returnvalue).

Comment: @gbn, it was given here in this question which you also answered: http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#returnvalue

Comment: [Erland here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/b39cb2e5-3d49-4266-84dc-565b11ad0ffa/) says the the return value is 10 minus the severity level of the error but I can't see that mentioned in the linked article.

Comment: I copied some information to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035789/return-value-from-a-stored-proc-on-error/77573298#77573298