# Standard @RETURN_VALUE's are in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, return-value

Can anyone point me to a list/description of standard @RETURN_VALUES in SQL Server 2005 (if such a thing exists)?  I have searched multiple times and can't find any reference.  Interestingly, I was debugging a stored procedure earlier today using Visual Studion 2008 and received this in the results--"@RETURN_VALUE = -6".  Wondering what -6 means and where the master list for these values is.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965211/sql-server-stored-procedure-return-code-oddity but I can't see a definite conclusion on that question (other than it isn't documented).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any agreement for stored procedure return values beyond:

- 0: success
- > 0 : error
- < 0 : critical error

Answer (score 0):

Some (system) stored procedures are documented. And the documentation (SQL help) tells about the possible return values and their meanings.
Additional to what Ken wrote there is 
0 - nothing done

> 0 - number of XXX (sent mails, deleted entries, ...)
>   <0 (except for comparison) is (like Ken wrote) an error

Answer (score 0):

There is some slight [logic behind "standard" codes](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#returnvalue).

[I asked similar here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965211) when I got -4