# SQL Stored Procedure to return results with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I want to create a stored procedure that returns the results of a search for "similar records". The stored procedure  i currently have is as follows

```
CREATE PRODECURE [dbo].[viewSimilarRecords]
 @recordType varchar(25),
 @recordSource varchar(25)

 AS 
SELECT * FROM myTableName 
WHERE
(recordtype = @recordType) AND
(recordsource = @recordSource)

 GO
```

The problem i'm having is that when it executes i get a return value 0 and the resulting rows do not show up (SQL Server Management Studio).

I can confirm i'm passing the correct values in the params and that multiple records do exist.

This is the execute Statement when it's ran

```
USE [databasename]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[ViewSimilarRecords]
    @recordType = N'Error',
    @recordSource = N'Local'


 SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

 GO
```

Comment: Can you show your execute statement?

Can you paste in some sample parameters and some actual data that should be returned?

Comment: Please post your data and what parameters you are passing.

Comment: Well, your syntax is invalid, you're missing a comma between your parameters.  Do you have any records in myTableName where both conditions are true?

Comment: The comma was actually in my code, i just missed it when posting here. I've now updated the example and included the execute results

Comment: Do you realize that your stored procedure does not return an integer, yet you're trying to jam the results into an integer? Just use 
`EXEC [dbo].[ViewSimilarRecords]
    @recordType = N'Error',
    @recordSource = N'Local'` and see if that works

Comment: @hamlin - That's just the code SSMS generates. The implicit return code is 0 [unless an error occurs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965211/sql-server-stored-procedure-return-code-oddity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information to go on, I'm just guessing but perhaps no data matches your parameters.  the procedure is `viewSimilarRecords` and not `viewExactmatchingRecords`.  The way it is coded you must have an exact match for every parameter.  Possibly you need to try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[viewSimilarRecords]
 @recordType varchar(25),
 @recordSource varchar(25)

 AS 
SELECT * FROM myTableName 
WHERE
(recordtype  =@recordType   OR @recordType IS NULL) AND --<<change to OR??
(recordsource=@recordSource OR @recordSource IS NULL)
                          --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 GO
```

you could take a look at this: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: `PRODECURE` and no commas in the param list ;)

Comment: I have verified data does exist that matches the parameters, if i copy/paste from the table directly and run a SELECT query i get results

Comment: @Khalid Rahaman, something must be wrong with the way the parameters are being passed into the procedure, verify that they have the values you think the do in the application, echo/print/display/log them just before the stored procedure call.  if they are still the values that you think they should be, add an insert into a log table at the start of the procedure and record the parameter values, and verify that they are passed into the procedure as what you think they should be.

Comment: @Khalid Rahaman, in your edited question, you are passing in nvarchar values but your procedure has varchar parameters, possibly you loose something converting to ASCII and you don't find the rows you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Check all of the little (*obviously, it could never be that...*) things...

1) Verify the procedure exists.  In your create statement, you mis-spelled p-r-o-****c***-e-****d***-u-r-e

2) When you execute, you're enforcing unicode (N') on non-unicode variables.

```
@recordType = N'Error', @recordSource = N'Local'
```

Try this instead:

```
@recordType =  'Error', @recordSource =  'Local'
```

3) Instantiate the parameters and run just this part of the procedure directly (highlight and press F5) to make sure you get results.

```
 ECLARE @recordType varchar(25)
 ECLARE @recordSource varchar(25) 
 SET @recordType = 'Error'
 SET @recordSource = 'Local'
 SELECT * FROM myTableName 
 WHERE
 (recordtype = @recordType) AND
 (recordsource = @recordSource)
```

4) Run this directly, all by itself (if item 3 above was successful to verify that you're in the right database:

```
   EXEC [dbo].[ViewSimilarRecords] 'Error','Local'
```

Comment: 5) If on a CS collation check that there aren't 2 versions of the procedure. `viewSimilarRecords` vs `ViewSimilarRecords`