# What is the default return type of store procedure give with example?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

The following Stored Procedure accepts EmployeeId as a parameter. It checks whether an Employee with the supplied EmployeeId exists in the Employees table of the Northwind database.

What will be the default return type and value?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckEmployeeId
  @EmployeeId INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Exists INT

  IF EXISTS(SELECT EmployeeId
                    FROM Employees
                    WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId)
  BEGIN
        SET @Exists = 1
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
        SET @Exists = 0
  END

  RETURN @Exists
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever, you execute a procedure, it returns an integer status variable.Usually,**zero** indicates success and **non-zero** indicates failure.

Now. its depends on you, what integer value you want to return from procedure to inform your application.

A procedure can return an integer value called a return code to indicate the execution status of a procedure. You specify the return code for a procedure using the RETURN statement.

Suppose you have

```
Return code value       Meaning
0                       Employee does not exists.
1                       Employee exists.
```

**Example:-**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckEmployeeId
  @EmployeeId INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF EXISTS(SELECT EmployeeId
                    FROM Employees
                    WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId)
  BEGIN
        RETURN(1)  
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
        RETURN(0)  
  END

  RETURN(0)  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

`RETURN` [always](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns `int` from a stored procedure.

The default value can vary if
- try to return NULL (get zero and a warning)
- you get a [SQL Server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965211/sql-server-stored-procedure-return-code-oddity) where you get a value "10 minus the severity level of the error"

But it's always `int`