# TSQL - Return value from sp when sp does not contain return

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is called by another stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Test] 
AS
begin
declare @errorCode int
declare @lastIdentity int
select @errorCode = @@ERROR
    if @errorCode=0
    begin
        update Vehicle  set model='1996----------'
            where Make='MERC'
        select @errorCode = @@ERROR
        select @lastIdentity = @@IDENTITY
    end 

print 'usp_test lastIdentity='  + convert(varchar(10), isnull(@lastIdentity,0)) 
print 'usp_test errorCode=' + convert(varchar(10), @errorCode) 

end
```

If I call the stored procedure like this

```
declare @RetVal int

exec @RetVal=usp_Test

print 'return value is ' + convert(varchar(10), @RetVal)
```

I get the following messages

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure usp_Test, Line 14
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
usp_test lastIdentity=0
usp_test errorCode=8152
return value is -6

By adding RETURN 0 at the end and RETURN @errorCode after the select @errorCode... I will have a nice clean way of returning the error and subsequently handle it.  I am surprise that without any RETURN's I get a return value of -6.  Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: don't use @@IDENTITY : use scope_identity(). 99.999 times out of a 100 you want scope_identity().

Comment: Yes I agree,  I am working on a project where the code was written by someone else.  This however, is not really related to the question I asked

Comment: Duplicate of [SQL Server stored procedure return code oddity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965211/sql-server-stored-procedure-return-code-oddity). Whichlinks to http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#returnvalue

Comment: Thanks @gbn, this isn't really a duplication, but the answer given there is exactly what I was after.

Comment: I never said it was. You can choose to ignore good advice anytime you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035789/return-value-from-a-stored-proc-on-error/1040244#1040244)

> If you have a RETURN statement with an
>   explicit return value, that is of
>   course the return value.
>
> But if there is no RETURN statement,
>   but an error occurs during execution,
>   the return value is 10 minus the
>   severity level of the error. Division
>   by zero is level 16, thus the return
>   value is -6. Permissions errors are
>   typical level 14, thus the return
>   value is -4.
>
> As you may guess this is not terribly
>   useful, but this: 0 is success, and
>   everything else is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The standard return value when you did not specify anything and the procedure executed correctly is 1.

When the procedure returns an error and you did not specify a return value the default returned is 10 - errorlevel with a maximum value of 0.

for example:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE p_error16
    AS 
    RAISERROR('error', 16, 1)
    GO
```

will return -6 where the following proc will return -7:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE p_error17
    AS 
    RAISERROR('error', 17, 1)
    GO
```

if the errorlevel goes under 10 the value returned is 0:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE p_error5
    AS 
    RAISERROR('error', 5, 1)
    GO
```

Comment: thanks for that.  Are you sure the standard return value when no return is specified is 1 and not 0.  I seem to be getting a 0 back as the return value if my stored procedures execure as expected

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains the answer I was looking for:
http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#returnvalue

This is an extract.
"All stored procedures have a return value, determined by the RETURN statement. The RETURN statement takes one optional argument, which should be a numeric value. If you say RETURN without providing a value, the return value is 0 if there is no error during execution. If an error occurs during execution of the procedure, the return value may be 0, or it may be a negative number. The same is true if there is no RETURN statement at all in the procedure: the return value may be a negative number or it may be 0. "

Comment: I believe that is the same person who wrote the answer I copied above