# SQL Server return code -6, what does it mean?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, return-value

I have a stored procedure that works with no issues, that is the return code is 0.  In some cases I RAISERROR a user defined error (> 50000).  In those cases the return is -6.  I am just curious, what does -6 mean?  I do not set the return code in the procedure, so this number is SQL Server (system) generated.

I found this statement:

> Whether these negative numbers have any meaning, is a bit difficult to
>   tell. It used to be the case, that the return values -1 to -99 were
>   reserved for system-generated return values, and Books Online for
>   earlier versions of SQL Server specified meanings for values -1 to
>   -14. However, Books Online for SQL 2000 is silent on any such
>   reservations, and does not explain what -1 to -14 would mean.

Does anyone know the "hidden" meanings to these return codes?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server stored procedure return code oddity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965211/sql-server-stored-procedure-return-code-oddity)

Comment: @gbn - Questions very similar, it is odd that is it returning -6, I just am curious to what -6 means (if anything).  I don't look at the return codes, but in case anyone ever did in the future.

Comment: Check the link and answers and comments and more link then... they tell where -6 comes from

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I found this...

[Return value from a stored proc on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035789/return-value-from-a-stored-proc-on-error)

```
If you have a RETURN statement with an explicit return value, that is of course the return value.
```

> But if there is no RETURN statement, but an error occurs during
>   execution, the return value is 10 minus the severity level of the
>   error. Division by zero is level 16, thus the return value is -6.
>   Permissions errors are typical level 14, thus the return value is -4.

In my case, the severity of the error I was raising was 16, so 10 - 16 = -6.

Thanks everyone for thier input.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got this myself and was wondering about it.