# Getting a result feedback from a stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

In a SQL Server 2008 I have a simple stored procedure moving a bunch of records to another table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].MyProc(@ParamRecDateTime [datetime])
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [dbo].Table2 
SELECT 
...,
    ...
FROM [dbo].Table1 
      WHERE RecDateTime <= @ParamRecDateTime    

DELETE FROM [dbo].Table1 
      WHERE RecDateTime <= @ParamRecDateTime        
END
```

Running it from within SQL Server Management Studio, I get the job done and return value = 0

```
 DECLARE @return_value int
 EXEC    @return_value = dbo.MyProc @ParamRecDateTime = '2011-06-25 11:00:00.000'
 SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

But when I call the same stored procedure from an app using Entity framework, I also get the job done but the return value is "-1":

```
int result = myrepository.MyProc(datetimePar);
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

I didn't manage to find an explanation for this error, but found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035789/return-value-from-a-stored-proc-on-error) discouraging post, where it's said that there is no standard for this type of return codes in SQL Server.

**What is the good, reliable way of getting know of a Stored Procedure execution result when calling it from Entity Framework and when the Stored Procedure doesn't return any entities?**

Comment: What if you remove 'SET NOCOUNT ON'?

Comment: @Wouter de Kort: Interesting! In this case, as a return value, I get a number of operations done, i.e. number of records moved, multiplied by 2. Is this what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Yes, it returns the number of records affected.  In this case you are inserting and deleting the same number of records, hence the multiplication by 2.

Comment: Note, please, that in this case I get rid of the error "-1" in my app (using Entity Framework) and get that number of operations. When calling the stored procedure from inside the SQL Server Management Studio I still get 0 as before. It is just a note for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to call [`ExecuteStoreCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx), and pass in a `SqlParameter` with a direction of `Output`:

```
var dtparm = new SqlParameter("@dtparm", DateTime.Now);
var retval = new SqlParameter("@retval", SqlDbType.Int);

retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

context.ExecuteStoreCommand("exec @retval = MyProc @dtparm", retval, dtparm);

int return_value = (int)retval.Value;
```

Originally I tried using a direction of `ReturnValue`:

```
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

context.ExecuteStoreCommand("MyProc @dtparm", retval, dtparm);
```

but `retval.Value` would always be `0`.  I realized that `retval` was the result of executing the `MyProc @dtparm` statement, so I changed it to capture the return value of `MyProc` and return that as an output parameter.

Comment: Thanks, +1. It works as yet another approach. In my case it returns 0 when using `retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;` and gives the error `Must declare the scalar variable "@retval"` when using `retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;` (my EF function import is declared as "None" in "Return a Collection of").

Answer (score 2):

```
using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
{
var parameters = new[]
{
new SqlParameter("@1","Input Para value"),
new SqlParameter("@2",SqlDbType.VarChar,4){ Value = "default if you want"},
new SqlParameter("@3",SqlDbType.Int){Value = 0},
new SqlParameter("@4","Input Para Value"),
new SqlParameter("@5",SqlDbType.VarChar,10 ) {   Direction = ParameterDirection.Output   },
new SqlParameter("@6",SqlDbType.VarChar,1000) {   Direction = ParameterDirection.Output   }
};
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("EXEC SP_Name @1,@2,@3,@4,@5 OUT,@6 OUT", parameters);
ArrayList ObjList = new ArrayList();
ObjList.Add(parameters[1].Value);
ObjList.Add(parameters[2].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See OUTPUT attribute for SQL param of store procedure, 
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I had the same issue but needed multiple OUTPUT variables. The solution was a combination of both answers.  Below is a complete sample.

```
public void MyStoredProc(int inputValue, out decimal outputValue1, out decimal outputValue2)
{
    var parameters = new[] { 
        new SqlParameter("@0", inputValue), 
        new SqlParameter("@1", SqlDbType.Decimal) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }, 
        new SqlParameter("@2", SqlDbType.Decimal) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output } 
    };

    context.ExecuteStoreCommand("exec MyStoredProc @InParamName=@0, @OutParamName1=@1 output, @OutParamName2=@2 output", parameters);

    outputValue1 = (decimal)parameters[1].Value;
    outputValue2 = (decimal)parameters[2].Value;
}
```

Please note the Types used (decimal.)  If another type is needed, remember to not only change it in the method argument list but also the `SqlDbType.XXX`.