# ExecuteStoreQuery with an output value

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

does anyone know how I can return an output value using ExecuteStoreQuery along with the results from the stored procedure?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is my SP:

http://pastebin.com/KgGLTzEe

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteStoreQuery` executes SQL that produces a result set

You want `ExecuteFunction` (or `ExecuteStoreCommand`)

`ExecuteFunction` takes a list of Parameters for the stored procedure.

```
var parameter = new ObjectParameter("OutputParameterName", typeof(int));
var results = context.ExecuteFunction<YourEntity>("ProcName", 
    parameter
    ).ToList();
var parameterresult = parameter.Value;
```

Comment: I tried executestorecommand and got the following error: No mapping exists from object type System.RuntimeType to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: I tried execute function and got this error:No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: Yes - you have to import the SP into your model and map it to your entities or result types

Comment: I added my SP into my model, updated it countless times, and also tried the function mapping, it seems to show no columns returned when trying to create an object. When carrying out the query on the SP, it returns the correct data, but does not set the output value for some reason :(

Comment: Are you talking about an OUTPUT value, or the RETURN from the SP?

Comment: The OUTPUT value is always null

Comment: And you've changed OutputParameterName to "TotalRecords"?

Comment: Could be to do with the dynamic SQL in the SP confounding EF meaning you don't seee the columns returned. If the mapping doesn't work, try using ExecuteStoreCommand as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020751/getting-a-result-feedback-from-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework

Comment: I added ToList() to the executefunction to force it to execute.

Comment: Hi did this and got the following error: The stored procedure or function 'usp_BusinessUser_Search' does not have a return type. ExecuteFunction only supports stored procedures and functions that have a return type. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/4bW3fuYU