# C# stored procedure check if success

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have a store procedure which inserts, deletes or updates rows in my db and doesn't return any value. I am calling it from my C# code like this:

```
DAL.CDataContext dc = new DAL.CDataContext();
dc.MySproc();
```

How can I check that it run successfully?

Comment: What is your `CDataContext()`, what is your `MySproc()`. Anyway, you can try `executenonquery`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If it didn't throw, it run succesfully. Perhaps you mean something else? Not inserting or not updating isn't a failure.

Comment: Won't you get an exception if it fails? So if you don't get an exception, it must be successful... I am just speculating

Comment: *What* do you want to check? If you want to check which records were inserted/updated/deleted modify the stored procedure to return counts or IDs. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE have an `OUTPUT` clause that can return the modified data

Comment: Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020751/getting-a-result-feedback-from-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework)

Comment: What do *you* mean by "successful"? Just "no errors" (read: no exceptions), or "the rows that should be updated, are updated in the correct way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try catch. if there is no exception, then the query was ran successfully, then return true if sucess, return false if it isnt
example

```
public static bool InsertObFile(PreApprove p)
{
    var command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = "ObInsertPreApprove";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeAutoId", p.EmployeeAutoId).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", p.EmployeeId).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", p.DateFrom).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", p.DateTo).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", p.Description).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateUserId", p.CreateUserId).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    try
    {
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(command); // this is where I run my stored procedure
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: But please (at least) log the exception. No you know just that some error occurred, but no details.