# SQL Server Return value after RAISERROR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raiserror

I have StoredProc1 calling StoredProc2.
StoredProc2 then performs some validations and if any fail, it issues a RAISERROR.
For e.g. following is pseduocode for StoredProc2

```
BEGIN  
    --Perform validation1, validation2  
    IF validation1 Failed OR Validation2 failed
    BEGIN  
         RAISERROR('Something wrong', 16, 1)  
         RETURN  
    END  
END
```

In StoredProc1, I have

```
BEGIN  
    EXEC @ReturnVal = StoredProc2  
    IF @ReturnVal <> 0  
    BEGIN  
       RETURN  
    END  
END
```

My question is regarding StoredProc2's RETURN keyword immediately after the RAISERROR.
Since I have not explicitly specified RETURN  like RETURN -1, what will be the return value from StoredProc2?

Thanks
Vikas

Comment: did you try executing both and debug by explicitly raising error from SP2 and see what values are returned?

Comment: Yes. it returns a negative number. I had a doubt coz I want to know how the return value is determined for the inner procedure after the raiserror. Could not find in MSDN.

Comment: check [this SO QA Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1040244/125551)

Comment: Cool. Got it. Thanks a lot RS. Thats why I kept getting -6.